# Does this show how fatou's lemma scores over dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f_n:(0,1)\to \mathbb R$ be defined as follows:
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
2n, &  \frac 1 {2n} \leq x \leq \frac 1 n \\
0, &  x\in (0,\frac 1 {2n})\cup (\frac 1 n, 1 ).
\end{cases}$$
Compute $\int_{0}^1 \lim f_n$ and $\lim \int_0 ^1 f_n$. Does this show how Fatou's lemma scores over the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: Just compute the integrals for a start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest computing the integral/ limit yourself as an exercise to internalize the fact that the inequality in Fatou's Lemma, which involves $lim \int f_n$ and $\int lim f_n$, can be a strict inequality and remember which way the inequality goes. But if you really want to see a solution:

> $\int_{0}^{1}lim f_n(x) = \int_{0}^{1} 0$ since $f_n$ converges to the $0$ function (you can clearly see this since the interval $(\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{n})$ decreases in size as $n \rightarrow +\infty$, so $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$.
>
> On the other other hand, $lim\int_{0}^{1} f_n(x)$ = $\int_{0}^{1} f_n(x)$  $\forall$ $n \in \mathbb{N}$, since no matter how large $n$ becomes, the integral $\int_{\frac{1}{2n}}^{\frac{1}{n}} f_n(x)$, which is equal to the integral of the function on the unit interval, is exactly the measure of a box with length $2n$ and width $\frac{1}{2n}$ will always have measure $1$, so $lim\int f_n(x) = 1$.

You can then conclude Fatou's Lemma in fact holds and use this example as a way to remember that $lim \int f_n \geq \int lim f_n$ (as opposed to the other way around). I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "scores over the Dominated Convergence Theorem." They are both key theorems involving Lebesgue Integrals, and neither supersedes the other. One involves limits of integrals and another states that limits of integrals and integrals of limits are two different things. In fact, the actual statement of Fatou involves lim infs rather than integrals themselves. To understand lim infs, I'd recommend reading about envelope sequences.